# Correct use of Icicle Coroutine

Tags: php

I am learning the [PHP Icicle Library](https://github.com/icicleio/Icicle)

I wanted to know the use of Coroutine. I understood how it works. It basically executes a generator function asynchronously.....when a value is yielded it lets the event loop execute another task from the asynchronous queue.

If possible provide a code example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples in the Icicle documentation on coroutines here: https://github.com/icicleio/Icicle/wiki/Coroutines.

When a coroutine yields a promise, execution of the coroutine is interrupted until the promise is resolved, allowing other tasks to be run.

Below is an example from the documentation, showing how a coroutine can yield to the promises returned from the resolver and connector to asynchronously connect to a server.

```
use Icicle\Coroutine\Coroutine;
use Icicle\Dns\Executor\Executor;
use Icicle\Dns\Resolver\Resolver;
use Icicle\Loop;
use Icicle\Socket\Client\Connector;

$generator = function () {
    try {
        $resolver = new Resolver(new Executor('8.8.8.8'));

        // Coroutine pauses until yielded promise is fulfilled or rejected.
        $ips = (yield $resolver->resolve('example.com'));

        $connector = new Connector();

        // Coroutine pauses again until yielded promise is fulfilled or rejected.
        $client = (yield $connector->connect($ips[0], 80));

        echo "Asynchronously connected to example.com:80\n";
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo "Asynchronous task failed: {$exception->getMessage()}\n";
    }
};

$coroutine = new Coroutine($generator());

Loop\run();
```

I encourage you thoroughly read all the documentation at https://github.com/icicleio/Icicle/wiki and ask more specific questions if you have trouble implementing something.